# localeCompare yields different results in different Node.js versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, v8, ecmascript-intl

localeCompare yields different results in different Node.js versions, and I am trying to find out exactly why this is happening.

Specifically, Node 12.22.12 vs 13.0.0

```
$ nvm use 12.22.12
Welcome to Node.js v12.22.12.
Type ".help" for more information.
> "topic".localeCompare("топик", "ru")
-1

$ nvm use 13.0.0
Welcome to Node.js v13.0.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> "topic".localeCompare("топик", "ru")
1
```

Didn't find anything in the Nodejs [changelogs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) from 12 and 13

Only thing I could find was maybe [this change in v8 engine on version 7.6](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-76), however, when I check the v8 version in the node 12.17.0 console, i get:

```
> console.log(process.versions.v8)
7.8.279.23-node.37
```

Which is higher than 7.6, so it can't be that v8 change.

So, what's causing Node 12.22.12 and Node 13.0.0 to yield different results when running

```
"topic".localeCompare("топик", "ru")
```

?

Note: running these locally on a Mac, but seeing same results in our Linux CI

Comment: Have you tried the options for checking and setting locale support in https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localeCompare` is usually handled by ICU, so ICU updates in node would be relevant changes to look out for. Perhaps [this one](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V13.md#2019-10-22-version-1300-current-bethgriggs) from 13.0:

> **• build:**
> ◦ Node.js releases are now built with default full-icu support. This means that all locales supported by ICU are now included and Intl-related APIs may return different values than before (Richard Lau) [#29887](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/29887).

That's just a guess though.